# Error while domxml parsing for XML file

Tags: php, mysql, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers

In php, i am trying to parse xml file and further i need to populate in mysql for "LABEL" field in below xml file, where sample xml file be as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<markers>
<marker ALPS="ALPS00000000" FILE="LOG_1"  time="2014-11-11 10:16:21" LABEL="09 "  />
<marker ALPS="ALPS00000000" FILE="LOG_1"  time="2014-11-11 10:16:36" LABEL="s04" />
<marker ALPS="ALPS00000000" FILE="LOG_1"  time="2014-11-11 10:17:26" LABEL="s04" />
<markers>
```

I am using xmlDOM parsing for xml. but i am getting error as:
 Unable to parse the file C:\xampp\tmp\phpD0D.tmp
Please help

Code:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load( $_FILES ['upload_file']['tmp_name'] );    

$searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "marker" ); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{ 
    $label = $searchNode->getAttribute('LABEL');
    // get other attributes here!
    if(array_key_exists($label, $this->events))
    {
      $this->events[$label]["Count"]++;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->events[$label] = array("Type" => $label,
                                                 "Host" => $this->Network,
                                                 "Count" => 1);
    }

    //echo "$label\n"; 
} 
  $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad quotes in first element:

```
 <marker ALPS="ALPS00000000" FILE="LOG_1"  time="2014-11-11 10:16:21" LABEL="09” "  />
```